# Access Github repository through GCP Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-build

I'm trying to connect private Github repository to GCP Cloud Build and following the below documentation https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-github-from-build

While trying to submit the build by using the following command -

```
gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml .
```

I get the below error -

```
Creating temporary tarball archive of 324 file(s) totalling 38.0 MiB before compression.
Uploading tarball of [.] to [gs://MYPROJECT_cloudbuild/source/350297308.2427560-0895i34250f90i08071432452350.tgz]
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: builder service account "PROJECTNUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" does not have secretmanager.versions.access permissions for secret "projects/MYPROJECT/secrets/MYSECRET"
```

I'm trying to find the Cloud Build default service a/c - `PROJECTNUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` but it's not present and the Google documentation says that when Cloud Build API is enabled this service a/c is created by default.
https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/cloud-build-service-account
That didn't happen in this case, and I can't seem to create a service a/c with this id - `PROJECTNUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`. Can you please help me here?

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: builder service account "PROJECTNUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" does not have secretmanager.versions.access permissions for secret "projects/MYPROJECT/secrets/MYSECRET"
```

Seems like an issue with missing, adding the `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` role. You can add this role to your service account by following the steps mentioned in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-github-from-build#grant_permissions).

> You need to grant the Cloud Build service account permission to access Secret Manager during the build.
>
> 1. Open the IAM page in the Google Cloud console:
> 2. Open the IAM page
> 3. Select your project and click Open.
> 4. In the permissions table, locate the email ending with @cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com, and click on the pencil icon.
> 5. Add **Secret Manager Secret Accessor role**.
> 6. Click Save.

Or you can assign the missing role `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` to your service account by going to the [Cloud build settings page](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account#service-account-permissions-settings) following the steps.

> 1.Open the Cloud Build Settings page:
>
> 2.You'll see the **Service account permissions** page:
>
> 3.Set the status of the role you wish to add to Enable.

You can find the `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` role enable it there.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, 
I tried to assign the role to the default compute engine svc a/c 
XXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com -
Artifact Registry Administrator
Cloud Build Editor
Editor
Secret Manager Secret Accessor
Because there was not other service a/c created for Cloud Build

Comment: Are you still facing the issue? Have you tried with the second document? If you are still facing the issue you can try by creating the new `Service account` by following this [Document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-create).

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thanks for the input but I was able to assign the `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` role to the default svc a/c successfully and then it worked!